# How to select limit data from a column?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have column for a news content and I have a preview for the news and I want half of the news to be previewed.

How can I control the amount of data when I select the content from the column name?

This is my code:

```
$select_upevent="SELECT * FROM upevent";
$result_upevent=mysqli_query($con,$select_upevent);
```

---

```
<?php while ($row_upevent=mysqli_fetch_array($result_upevent)) { ?>
<tr>
  <td width="16%"><img src="../site/images/event/<?php echo $row_upevent['img_name'] ?>" alt=""></td>
  <td width="16%"><?php echo $row_upevent['title'] ?></td>
  <td width="16%"><?php echo $row_upevent['content'] ?></td>
  <td width="16%"><?php echo $row_upevent['place'] ?></td>
  <td width="16%"><?php echo $row_upevent['date'] ?></td>
  <td width="10%"><a href="php/delete-event.php?delevent=<?php echo $row_upevent['id'] ?>"><img class="imgdelete" src="images/delete.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/delete-hvr.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/delete.png'"/></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you can use CSS/jQuery for this, saving you an extra query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
$select_upevent="SELECT `title` , LEFT(`content` , 30 )  as `content`,`place`,`date` FROM upevent LIMIT 5";
```

This will show only 30 character of the content by using { LEFT(`content` , 30 )  as `content`  } and the LIMIT 5 will determine that only 5 news will be shown.

Comment: Can you please upvote this answer and Mark as correct answer now ? :)  @belal

Comment: of caurse >> i'm waiting this message ^_^ "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes" @Aniruddha Chakraborty

Comment: problem with this is, if OP wants to show full content, a separate query will be required.

Comment: yeap! @Fred-ii- .. He can Create a link with an ID to show full content in another page ..

Comment: exactly , this is what i plan to do.@Aniruddha Chakraborty, thank you a lot.@Fred -ii-

Answer (score 0):

This a duplicate question, but include `LIMIT` to your query; example

```
SELECT * FROM upevent LIMIT 5
```

Comment: no i meant to limit the amount of data not to limit number of rows , thanks anyway a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add a `limit` clause to the end of your SQL query

Comment: no i meant to limit the amount of data not to limit number of rows , thanks anyway a lot